# A pop up window to login in

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have wrote some code and want to build a pop up window for user to login when they press the login button. However, I can't do that and can't figure out what is wrong in the code. Would someone kindly help on this issue? Thanks a lot

Below is the html code:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/timetabling.css">
        <title>Time-tabling system</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="main">
            <div id="header">
                <div id="widgetBar">

                    <div class="button">
                        <button class="btn login">Login</button>

                        <div class="popup">
                            <div class="popup-content">
                                <img scr="close.png" alt="Close" class="close">
                                <input type="text" placeholder="username">
                                <input type="password" placeholder="password">
                                <a href="#" class="button">Login</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <script>                        
                        document.getElementByID("button").addEventListener("click", function(){
                            document.querySelector(".popup").style.display = "flex";
                        })

                        document.querySelector(".close").addEventListener("click", function(){
                            document.querySelector(".popup").style.diplay = "none";
                        })
                        </script>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <img align="center" src="keep-habbit-tracking.jpg" alt="habbit" width="600" height="300">
            <p align="center">Welcome to the time-tabling system!!</p>
            <p align="center">This is a place for you to set your time table and schedule your work...</p>
            <p align="center">Please login to begin</p>

            <div id="footer">
                <hr>
                <p id="footerText">Group 18 The time tabling system</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Below is the css code:

```
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    width: 850px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 20px auto;
}

#main { background: #eee }

#widgetBar {
    height: 50px;
    width: 850px;
    float: right;
    background: #ccc;
}

.btn {
  border: none;
  background-color: inherit;
  padding: 14px 28px;
  font-size: small;
  float:right;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
}

.btn:hover {background: #eee;}

.login {color: green;}

.popup{
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    display: none;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.popup-content{
    height: 250px;
    width: 500px;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: relative;
}

input{
    margin: 20px auto;
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 8px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}

.close{
    position: absolute;
    top: -15px;
    right: -15px;
    background: #fff;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 6px 6px 29px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    cursor: pointer;
}

#footer {
    height: 60px;
    width: 300px;
    font-size: small;
    clear: left;
}
```

This is the page it should look like after I run the code. But when I click in the login button, the pop up window doesn't exist for user to login. 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

A few things to note `getElementById` is a lowercase D at the end. I think sticking to that besides the `querySelector` is at least how I would do it (If not using JQuery). Add your script tag and all javascript after the body. Don't add it into your code. It gets messy and impossible to read after a while. And if you are using `getElementById('button')` make sure it's an ID and not a class.

```js
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "flex";
})

document.getElementById("close").addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.getElementById("popup").style.diplay = "none";
})
```

```css
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    width: 850px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 20px auto;
}

#main { background: #eee }

#widgetBar {
    height: 50px;
    width: 850px;
    float: right;
    background: #ccc;
}

.btn {
  border: none;
  background-color: inherit;
  padding: 14px 28px;
  font-size: small;
  float:right;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
}

.btn:hover {background: #eee;}

.login {color: green;}

.popup{
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    display: none;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.popup-content{
    height: 250px;
    width: 500px;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: relative;
}

input{
    margin: 20px auto;
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 8px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}

.close{
    position: absolute;
    top: -15px;
    right: -15px;
    background: #fff;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 6px 6px 29px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    cursor: pointer;
}

#footer {
    height: 60px;
    width: 300px;
    font-size: small;
    clear: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/timetabling.css">
        <title>Time-tabling system</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="main">
            <div id="header">
                <div id="widgetBar">

                    <div class="button">
                        <button class="btn login" id="button">Login</button>

                        <div class="popup" id="popup">
                            <div class="popup-content">
                                <img scr="close.png" alt="Close" class="close" id="close">
                                <input type="text" placeholder="username">
                                <input type="password" placeholder="password">
                                <a href="#" class="button">Login</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <img align="center" src="keep-habbit-tracking.jpg" alt="habbit" width="600" height="300">
            <p align="center">Welcome to the time-tabling system!!</p>
            <p align="center">This is a place for you to set your time table and schedule your work...</p>
            <p align="center">Please login to begin</p>

            <div id="footer">
                <hr>
                <p id="footerText">Group 18 The time tabling system</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here the best example to create Popup Box.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: #aaaaaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Modal Example</h2>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
  </div>

</div>

<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `d` was incorrect in `getElementByID` ,Instead of `getElementByID` you need to use `getElementById`. Here is documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById
Also while defining `style` to `popup`, there was a spelling mistake of `display`

**Here is a snippet:**

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("button");
var closeBtn = document.querySelector(".close");
var popupId = document.getElementById("popup");
btn.addEventListener("click", function(){ 
   popupId.style.display = "flex";
}) 
closeBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){
   popupId.style.display = "none";
})
```

```css
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    width: 850px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 20px auto;
}

#main { background: #eee }

#widgetBar {
    height: 50px;
    width: 850px;
    float: right;
    background: #ccc;
}

.btn {
  border: none;
  background-color: inherit;
  padding: 14px 28px;
  font-size: small;
  float:right;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
}

.btn:hover {background: #eee;}

.login {color: green;}

.popup{
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    display: none;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.popup-content{
    height: 250px;
    width: 500px;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: relative;
}

input{
    margin: 20px auto;
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 8px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}

.close{
    position: absolute;
    top: -15px;
    right: -15px;
    background: #fff;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 6px 6px 29px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    cursor: pointer;
}

#footer {
    height: 60px;
    width: 300px;
    font-size: small;
    clear: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/timetabling.css">
        <title>Time-tabling system</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="main">
            <div id="header">
                <div id="widgetBar">

                    <div class="button">
                        <button class="btn login" id="button">Login</button>

                        <div class="popup" id="popup" style="display:none">
                            <div class="popup-content">
                                <img scr="close.png" alt="Close" class="close">
                                <input type="text" placeholder="username">
                                <input type="password" placeholder="password">
                                <a href="#" class="button" >Login</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <img align="center" src="keep-habbit-tracking.jpg" alt="habbit" width="600" height="300">
            <p align="center">Welcome to the time-tabling system!!</p>
            <p align="center">This is a place for you to set your time table and schedule your work...</p>
            <p align="center">Please login to begin</p>

            <div id="footer">
                <hr>
                <p id="footerText">Group 18 The time tabling system</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
document.getElementByID("button").addEventListener("click", function(){
```

Change to:

```
document.getElementById("login_button").addEventListener("click", function(){
```

And add an id to the login button:

```
<button class="btn login" id="login_button">Login</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
  /*Modal*/
  h4 {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
  }
  .close {
    color: #fff;
    transform: scale(1.2)
  }
  .modal-content {
    font-weight: bold;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom right,#F87E7B,#B05574);
  }
  .form-control {
    margin: 1em 0;
  }
  .form-control:hover, .form-control:focus {
    box-shadow: none;  
    border-color: #fff;
  }
  .username, .password {
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #eee;
    padding-left: 0;
    font-weight: normal;
    background: transparent;  
  }
  .form-control::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #eee;  
  }
  .form-control:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
  }
  .login {
    padding: 6px 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background: none;
    border: 2px solid #FAB87F;
    color: #FAB87F;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: all .5s;
    margin-top: 1em;
  }
  .login:hover {
    background: #FAB87F;
    color: #fff;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
<body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
     <li><a href="#" href="#" data-target="#login" data-toggle="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
   </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  
  <div class="container">
     <img align="center" src="keep-habbit-tracking.jpg" alt="habbit" width="600" height="300" style="margin-left:250px;">
     <p align="center">Welcome to the time-tabling system!!</p>
     <p align="center">This is a place for you to set your time table and schedule your work...</p>
     <p align="center">Please login to begin</p>
  </div>
  <!--MODEL POPUP FOR LOGIN-->
  <div id="login" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">   
   <div class="modal-content">
     <div class="modal-body">
    <button data-dismiss="modal" class="close">&times;</button>
    <h4>Login</h4>
    <form>
      <input type="text" name="username" class="username form-control" placeholder="Username"/>
      <input type="password" name="password" class="password form-control" placeholder="password"/>
      <center><input class="btn login" type="submit" value="Login" /></center>
    </form>
     </div>
   </div>
    </div>  
  </div>
  <!--END MODEL POPUP FOR LOGIN-->

</body>
</html>
```